# dplyr `mutate` returns error when used twice

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems that, for certain kinds of objects stored in list-columns, `dplyr::mutate` will only work on them *once*.  That is, two successive uses of `mutate` causes an error.

```
library(dplyr)
one_mod <- data.frame(grp = "a", x = runif(5,0,1)) %>%
  tbl_df %>%
  mutate(y = rnorm(x,x*2,1)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  do(mod = lm(y~x,data = .))
```

This approach does not work:

```
one_mod %>%
  mutate(rsq = summary(mod)$r.squared) %>%
  mutate(aic = AIC(mod))
# Error: unsupported type for column 'mod' (VECSXP)
```

but this one does

```
one_mod %>%
  mutate(rsq = summary(mod)$r.squared,
     aic = AIC(mod))
#Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
#Groups: grp
#
#  grp     mod       rsq      aic
#1   a <S3:lm> 0.6615589 10.63317
```

Comment: Oh hmmm, we're probably losing the rowwise attribute. Can you please file a bug report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/d8de13354052f2c0625a4870e22c403f73d5684b).

As Hadley hinted, in the two `mutate` version, the first one did not create a `rowwise_df` object, which is our guarantee that each group only relates to one row of the data, so that we can refer to `mod` instead of `mod[[1]]`. Unless we know that the data can be considered `rowwise_df` we don't handle list columns with `mutate`.

All good now and using your example as a new [regression test](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/d8de13354052f2c0625a4870e22c403f73d5684b/tests/testthat/test-mutate.r#L222)

```
one_mod <- data.frame(grp = "a", x = runif(5,0,1)) %>%
  tbl_df %>%
  mutate(y = rnorm(x,x*2,1)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  do(mod = lm(y~x,data = .))
one_mod %>%
  mutate(rsq = summary(mod)$r.squared) %>%
  mutate(aic = AIC(mod))
# Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#   grp     mod        rsq      aic
# 1   a <S3:lm> 0.04744827 11.91253
```